# how to compare long string and filter data in c#

Tags: c#, list, filter, dataview

I'm reading data from a flat file (.csv) and put those data into a data table. Then I am filtering it as follows :

```
string sendregionPorts = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);
            JArray rport = JArray.Parse(sendregionPorts);
            List<Myports> pd = rport.Select(r => new Myports()
            {
                portcode = (string)r["PORT-CD"],
                portname = (string)r["PORT-NAME"]
            }).ToList();


            var getval = pd.Where(l => l.portname == "Palma de Mallorca").Select(l => l.portcode);
```

the list `pd` contains the "Palma de Mallorca" but it didn't give any result.every time it is null.I don't have idea.

Comment: Please list some of the components of pd list before declaring the getval variable. It is possible to have portname completed like "Palma de Mallorca", but the portcode to be null. And you're selecting a portcode there. `pd.Where(l => l.portname == "Palma de Mallorca").Select(l => l.portcode);`

Comment: is there any deeper sense in converting the table in a List<>?